# Estimate the support (~ confidence interval of the output) for a linear regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, confidence-interval, estimation, error

Consider a linear regression model like this:

[image]

I want to draw two margins, say upper- and lower-bounds, which **contains 95% of the data**.

Formally, given a regression model ($\hat{y} = Ax+B$), I want to find the margin with  $\epsilon$ length from each side of the regression line such that the absolute error of the model is less than a certain amount for 95% of the training data. In other words:

$| Ax_i+B - yi| < \epsilon$ for 95% of the $x_i$ values.

What is the proper term for this? How can I estimate it?

PS. The literature I found so far is mostly about the confidence intervals of the oracle values for slope and the base ("A" and "B"), but that's not what I am looking for.

PS. I am using Bayesian linear regression, but I guess the answer is oblivious to whether one uses Bayesian or ordinary linear regression.

Comment: It's unclear what you might be looking for.  If you want the bands to include 95% of the *data,* that's a simple algorithm.  But if you want them to include 95% of the *underlying distribution,* that's a statistical question answered by some form of a *tolerance interval.*

Comment: @whuber Perfecto. **tolerance interval** is what I was looking for. Perhaps we can say that the k% tolerance interval is an estimation of the k% margin for **future / test** data, right?

Comment: That would be a *prediction interval.*  It tends to be comparable in size to a tolerance interval, but the concept differs because future data are random and you have to account for that.